# Copying logs/files newer than X days from from Unix SFTP server to Windows using WinSCP .NET assembly in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

This code downloads the files from remote Unix server into Windows Server using WinSCP .NET assembly. But instead of copying all the logs files from the logs folder on the source Unix server into the destination Windows server, I just want it to copy logs for the last 30 day. The reason is I don't want it filling the C drive on the destination Window Server

```
param (
    $localPath = "d:\Logs\OnlineLogs",
    $remotePath = "/application/oracle",
    $fileName =  "int_access*.*"
)

try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Set up session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = ""
        UserName = ""
        Password = ""
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = ""
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 

    try
    {
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        $session.GetFiles(($remotePath + $fileName), ($localPath + $fileName)).Check()
    }
    finally
    {
        #Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [filemask with a time-constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time):

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions -Property @{
    FileMask = "*>=30D"
}

$session.GetFiles(
    (Join-Path $remotePath $fileName),
    [WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($localPath, "*.*"),
    $False, $transferOptions).Check()
```

*(You were also missing slash and backslash between path and filename, that's why I added `Join-Path` and [`RemotePath.Combine`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotepath_combine) calls).*

Comment: after the above modification script complies but files don't get transferred now

Comment: Post a log file (set `$session.SessionLogPath = "winscp.log"`).

Comment: isn't $session.open() same as the above line

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: while running the script am getting error "Cannot bind argument to parameter "Name" because it is null". sorry am new to powershell and googling this error does not help match

Comment: Remove the `try {` and `}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}` - this way you will be able to identify what line has caused the problem.